# Search engine, what to do when user wants 'all'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm an absolute noob to programming and over the past 10 days or so I have been building a 'buy sell trade' website for things.

Anyway I have got to the point where I now have the ability for people to register, post ads and reply to them... but now I want to have a page where they can search through the adverts.

The search form works on 3 fields, 'make', 'model' and 'caliber' (site is for guns)

```
    <form action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">
I'm looking for a 
<input type="text" name="make" class="autosuggestmake" placeholder="Manufacturer"/>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul class="resultmake"></ul>
        </div>

<input type="text" name="model" class="autosuggestmodel" placeholder="Model"/>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <ul class="resultmodel"></ul>
        </div>
in
<select name="caliber" >
    <option value="*">(Caliber) Any</option>
    <option value=".177">.177</option>
    <option value=".20">.20</option>
    <option value=".22">.22</option>
    <option value=".25">.25</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
```

This is posted as GET data which I 'catch' with this code:

```
    $advert = new Advert;
    if (empty($_GET) === true){
$adverts = $advert->fetch_all();
    } else {
$search_make = $_GET['make'];
$search_model = $_GET['model'];
$search_caliber = $_GET['caliber'];

$adverts = $advert->fetch_results($search_make, $search_model, $search_caliber);
    }
```

My fetch_results query is this:

```
    class Advert {
public function fetch_results($search_make, $search_model, $search_caliber) {
    global $pdo;

    $search_caliber = mysql_real_escape_string($search_caliber);
    $search_make = mysql_real_escape_string($search_make);
    $search_model = mysql_real_escape_string($search_model);

    if (empty($search_make) === true){
        $search_make = "*";
    } 

    if (empty($search_model) === true){
        $search_model = "*";
    } 

    $query = $pdo -> prepare("SELECT * FROM `adverts` WHERE make = '$search_make' AND model = '$search_model' AND caliber = '$search_caliber'");
    $query -> execute();

    return $query -> fetchAll();
}
```

On my last question someone told me to start using PDO, so I did :)

My problem is when someone fills in the make field on my form and nothing else it will return nothing. I thought if the get variables were blank I would append a * and it will return anything but this is not the case :( I've been searching but I think my problem is I don't know the correct words to search to find the cure for my problem...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You may be using PDO, but you're doing it badly.  Use prepared/parameterized queries.  How are you getting `mysql_real_escape_string()` to work without a MySQL connection anyway?  It needs to know the character set to work properly.  Maybe that's part of the problem you're having.

Comment: Outside of the listed 'bad practices' you want to look into the mysql `LIKE` command and the mysql wildcard operator `%`

Comment: @Brad thanks for the heads up on bad practices. Like I said I am new to this, so far I know its not perfect but I am still getting my head around it all. Thanks :)

I still have a MySQL connection live, I've not turned all my queries into PDO just yet...

Comment: @elzaer you are a legend, with this SQL query I got it working :D :D :d
SELECT * FROM `adverts` WHERE make LIKE '$search_make' AND model LIKE '$search_model' AND caliber LIKE '$search_caliber'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having implemented a site with this myself, I strongly recommend [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/). This is what craigslist uses. It is simple enough for your needs, yet powerful enough to grow with you.

Another alternative is [ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), which I'm told is very good as well.

Comment: That looks scary haha

I will read up on them though, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can take.  One is to rewrite the query in php based on the search conditions.

The other is a SQL solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM `adverts`
WHERE ('$search_make' = '' or make = '$search_make') AND
      ('$search_model' or model = '$search_model') AND
      ('$search_caliber' or caliber = '$search_caliber');
```

However, if the table has indexes on the columns, then this query probably will not use the indexes.  Writing the php to include only the clauses with values creates a more efficient query.

Comment: Please, post an answer that doesn't involve injecting arbitrary strings into a SQL query.  I know that isn't the point of the question, but people blindly copy/paste far too often.

Answer (score 0):

Either you let your users browse "all" -- Use case = some collector looking for odd items.

Or you have a "Search By" pull down and make your users choose at least one of the search categories.

You could just send an error message if all the search criteria are blank -- but this tends to annoy users more than leading them through a set of search option screens.

Comment: Rather than return nothing when fields are left blank I want to ignore it and just search on the fields they did fill in.

For example if they put 'remmington' into the make field and leave everything else blank i just want to return remmington guns... Hope this helps.